# Access previous message content from a user reply message on Telegram

Tags: c#, bots, message, telegram, reply

Does anyone know how can I access a previous message content when a user sends a reply message on Telegram?
for example:

James: hello

me: reply on James message with "hello friend"

here i want to get the hello message content or its message id in my telegram bot to process a command.

sth like this:

if(message.Contains("/delete")){

bot.DeleteMessageAsync(chatId, PreviousMessage or OriginalMessage ID)

}

PreviousMessage or OriginalMessage ID are equals to MessageId 
but instead of MessageId i want to use sth like those two

I have checked [telegram bot documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) and I did not find anything
How can i do it?

(Im using getUpdates method)

sorry for my poor English

Comment: Are you using WebHookes or getUpdates methods to receive message?

Comment: @Mihir Dave Im using getUpdates

Answer (score 0):

You can find the original message ID in `message.reply_to_message.message_id`. Naming could differ depends on the library you use. More information and other attributes that could be useful you can find in the official Telegram's documentation for [the Message object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message).